# Codeigniter's activerecord set() method is treating my values as column names

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-update

I am working on codeigniter framework. In which I have to edit a row in db with specific column.

I have tried belowcode BUT it gives me error :

> Unknown column 'Vendor_1360622286' in 'field list'
>
> ```
> UPDATE `vendors`
> SET vendor_id = Vendor_1360622286,
>     vendor_name = fsd,
>     vendor_address = fds,
>     vendor_phone = fsdf,
>     vendor_email = sdfsdfsd
> WHERE `vendor_id` = 'Vendor_1360622286'
> ```

Code :

```
$this->db->set('vendor_id', $data['vendor_id'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('vendor_name', $data['vendor_name'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('vendor_address', $data['vendor_address'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('vendor_phone', $data['vendor_phone'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('vendor_email', $data['vendor_email'], FALSE);
$this->db->where('vendor_id', $data['vendor_id']);
$status = $this->db->update('vendors');
```

Any idea, why it is giving me error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
$update_data=array("vendor_id"=> $data['vendor_id'],"vendor_name"=> $data['vendor_name'],"vendor_address"=> $data['vendor_address'],"vendor_phone"=> $data['vendor_phone'],"vendor_email"=> $data['vendor_email']);
$condi=array("vendor_id"=>$data['vendor_id']);
$this->db->where($condi);
$res=$this->db->update("vendors",$update_data);
if($res)
echo "Recored Updated";
else
echo "Not Updated";
```

Comment: No explanation why OPs code will not work and why he will write this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the third parameter to `set()` as `FALSE`, so it doesn't escape the string values properly. The query should be `UPDATE vendors SET vendor_id = 'Vendor_1360622286', vendor_name = 'fsd', vendor_address = 'fds', vendor_phone = 'fsdf', vendor_email = 'sdfsdfsd' WHERE vendor_id = 'Vendor_1360622286'`.

Just remove the `FALSE` parameters from the calls and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function update($data)
         {
             $db = $this->db;
             $db->where('vendor_id', $data['vendor_id'])->update('vendors', $data);

             if ($db->affected_rows())
             {
                 return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }
```

the data array must contain the id and all the information you want to change.